# Jaas Kerberos Authentication through test AD in virtual environment

Tags: java, oracle, kerberos, jaas

i was trying out [this example authentication code](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jgss/tutorials/AcnOnly.html#ConfigFile) from ORacle. The only thing I change is the logincontext

```
  try {
      lc = new LoginContext("SampleConfig", new TextCallbackHandler());
  }
```

my `jaas.conf` file looks like this

```
SampleConfig {
   com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required client=true    useTicketCache=false;
};
```

I put the conf file together with the class. However when i run it, it gives me this error

```
C:\AnotherDirectory> java -Djava.security.krb5.realm=corp.example.com -Djava.s
ecurity.krb5.kdc=corp.example.com -Djava.security.auth.login.config=jaas.conf JaasAcn

        at JaasAcn.main(JaasAcn.java:37)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: corp.example.com
        at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
        at java.net.InetAddress$1.lookupAllHostAddr(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getByName(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.krb5.internal.UDPClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.krb5.internal.NetClient.getInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.krb5.KdcComm$KdcCommunication.run(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.krb5.KdcComm$KdcCommunication.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.security.krb5.KdcComm.send(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.krb5.KdcComm.send(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.krb5.KdcComm.send(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.krb5.KrbAsReqBuilder.send(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.krb5.KrbAsReqBuilder.action(Unknown Source)
```

I am running a test AD in a VBox Host only adaptor. I guess I did not set up the AD properly. So I use the actual IP address (IPv4) instead.

```
C:\AnotherDirectory>java -Djava.security.krb5.realm=192.168.56.101 -Djava.secu
rity.krb5.kdc=192.168.56.101 -Djava.security.auth.login.config=jaas.config JaasAcn
Kerberos username [Administrator]: dorothy
Kerberos password for dorothy:
javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: null (68)
        at com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.attemptAuthentication(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.login(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.access$000(Unknown Source)
        at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(Unknown Source)
        at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(Unknown Source)
        at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(Unknown Source)
        at JaasAcn.main(JaasAcn.java:37)
Caused by: KrbException: null (68)
        at sun.security.krb5.KrbAsRep.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.krb5.KrbAsReqBuilder.send(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.krb5.KrbAsReqBuilder.action(Unknown Source)
        ... 14 more
Caused by: KrbException: Identifier doesn't match expected value (906)
        at sun.security.krb5.internal.KDCRep.init(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.krb5.internal.ASRep.init(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.krb5.internal.ASRep.<init>(Unknown Source)
        ... 17 more
class sun.security.krb5.KrbException
```

dorothy is a normal test user that I created using "Active Directory Users and Computers". Does this account need to be "Administrator" because the prompt says [Administrator]? I have also ticked the "Use Kerberos DES Encryption types" and also the AES 128, 256 support in the user profile.

This is my AD (win 2008 server) setup

```
C:\> ksetup
default realm = corp.example.com (NT Domain)
No user mappings defined.
```

How to solve this? I am guessing this is a AD config problem and not with JAas? thanks